# Randomize `status` value

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm trying to randomize the `status` returned by a Wiremock (version 2.33.2) endpoint.

Ideally, my configuration would be something like this:

```json
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "urlPattern": "/giglio/random/supplier-stock/.*",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": {
            "equalTo": "application/json"
          }
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": {{pickRandom 200 500}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but of course this is not a valid JSON so I get an error when trying to start Wiremock (`Error loading file...`).

If I wrap the offending line:

```json
...
      "response": {
        "status": "{{pickRandom 200 500}}"
      }
...
```

then Wiremock complains that it `Cannot deserialize value of type 'int' from String "{{pickRandom 200 500}}": not a valid 'int' value`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [wiremock docs](https://docs.wiremock.io/response-templating/random-values/) values should be wrapped with `'`.
Example

```json
{{pickRandom '1' '2' '3'}} // One of 1, 2 or 3
```

Try doing

```json
"response": {
    "status": "{{pickRandom '200' '500'}}"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the same exception.

Comment: it doesn't worked